# Injecting services in CanActivate in Angular2

Tags: angular, service, dependency-injection, angular2-guards

I am trying to create an auth Guard service for my routes. In this service I need to inject the UserAccountService I am using to return the current logged in user.

This is my guard:

```
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core'; 
import { CanActivate } from '@angular/router'; 
import { UserAccountService } from '../';


@Injectable() export class ClaimsGuardService implements CanActivate
{ 
   constructor(private user: UserAccountService) {    }

   canActivate(route, state) {
       return true;   
   } 
}
```

`UserAccountService` works fine injected in components, it is included in my `app.module`:

```
providers: [
  provideInterceptorService([
    new ServerURLInterceptor(new CookieService())
  ]),
   ClaimsGuardService,
   CookieService,
   UserAccountService,
],
```

Other services, such as `CookieService`, `Http`, etc, are injected just fine but the `UserAccountService` has this issue.

Below is the definition of the service:

```
 @Injectable()
 export class UserAccountService {

   private currentUser: any = {};

   constructor(private cookieService: CookieService, private http: InterceptorService) {
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just define a service for `canActivate` (like `CanActivateTeam`). If `CanActivateTeam` has constructor parameters they will be passed from DI.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/CanActivate-interface.html

> ```
> @NgModule({
>   imports: [
>     RouterModule.forRoot([
>       {
>         path: 'team/:id',
>         component: TeamCmp,
>         canActivate: [CanActivateTeam]
>       }
>     ])
>   ],
>   providers: [CanActivateTeam, UserToken, Permissions]
> })
> class AppModule {}
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your reply Gunter. Actually the problem was at this line:

```
import { UserAccountService } from '../';
```

I had to reference the UserAccountService from its actual location rather than from the `/index` file.